# Podriais ayudarme con el problema de JAVA

Tags: java, variables

Editar el programa Error.java:  Compilar el programa y elimine los errores explicando cuál es el error en cada caso. respuesta . Necesito averiguar cual seria la solución al problema que causa que no se pueda ejecutar correctamente el codigo. Gracias

```
public class Error {   
 public static void main(String[] name) {
  int x=3;
  int 1y = 4_000_000_000;
  long $z = 3;
  long w = 3_000_000_000;
  byte _q = 500;
  short a = 29393;
  long r = 5_000_000_000L;
  float f = 2.34;
  double d = 345.898;
  float j = 3.342f;
  byte o = 0b111111111;
  int $r = 30 + 0xFF;
  float g = 333_.039f;
  int e = 07+08;
  int u@! = 0B101+0B111;
  int sd = 0XE1+0XA1;
  boolean df*g = 0;
  boolean awe = false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hola, en esta linea `int 1y = 4_000_000_000;` estas instanciando una variable cuyo nombre inicia con un numero, lo cual no es aceptado en java.

Comment: No estamos aquí para resolver tareas a otros, sino para ayudar, así que te daré una guía: El nombre de una variable puede contener letras, números, el símbolo de dólar ($) o guión bajo (_). No puede empezar por número

Comment: Has intentado compilarlo? Porque el propio compilador te da muchas pistas de lo que está mal en cada caso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poniendo el codigo en un IDE me marca lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Explicaciones es:

- `int 1y = 4_000_000_000;`, inicia el nombre de una variable con numero, las variables de tipo int el maximo valor es 2,147,483,647.
- `long w = 3_000_000_000;` Nuevamente, las variables de tipo int el valor maximo es 2,147,483,647 (Necesitas agregar una l al final para poder indicar que es un long)
- `byte _q = 500;` Se necesita castear el 500 a byte `byte _q = (byte) 500`, porque 500 es un valor entero
- `float f = 2.34;` El 2.34 es un valor de tipo double, se necesita agregar una f al final `2.34f` para que sea considerado como flotante o castearse como flotante
- `byte o = 0b111111111;` El IDE esta detectando el numero 0b111111111 como un entero asi que tambien se necesita castear como byte.
- `float g = 333_.039f;` El guion bajo solamente puede estar entre numeros.
- `int u@! = 0B101+0B111;` Los nombres de variables no pueden llevar ! ni @.
- `boolean df*g = 0;` Los nombres de variables no pueden llevar *.

Answer (score 1):

El int 1y esta mal por las siguientes razones:

1. Las variables no pueden ser iniciadas por un numero
2. Estas metiendo barras en un numero con lo cual no se puede

Float g no puede llevar guiones bajos
Int e en las sumas los números no pueden llevar 0 delante igual en las siguientes int a este
Boolean df*g no puede ser iniciado en numero, simplemente en true o false
Byte como dice su palabra solo puede contener un byte y tampoco pueden contener letras

Estos son los fallos que e visto, si veo mas lo edito